# Should I use an external voltage reference with the PIC24F16KL402?

Tags: pic

The internal ADC of the 8-bit PICs I usually use are quite inaccurate. The datasheet for a PIC10F320 for example, states an initial accuracy of -7% to +6%. I usually use a TL431 or a LM336 with those. The only drawback is the current of a couple milliamps for the reference.
I was looking into the PIC24F16KL402 family which states a 1% accuracy (although I couldn't find an initial accuracy) which outperforms and external reference like the TL431. I can even get rid of the extra current for an external reference. So is there even a need for an external voltage reference?

Comment: I suppose the obvious time is when you need an accuracy better than 1%, 0.1% and better references are common and not super expensive.

Comment: You're right, but then the accuracy of the power supply starts taking over and you have to care about noise during adc readouts and that other stuff. 1% is good enough for this application.

Comment: what has power supply accuracy got to do with ADC accuracy when you have a stable reference. That's the whole idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main time to use an external reference will be when the in-built band gap reference doesn't offer enough accuracy for your application. I couldn't find a mention of 1% accuracy although it wouldn't surprise me if that was the typical accuracy. However from the relevant part of the table on page 201 of the [PIC24F16KL402 Datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/30001037c.pdf):

[image: Band Gap Voltage Reference]

So over the full operating range the reference may be as far as 5% from the typical voltage. From a comment you seem to have a bit of a misconception that an external voltage reference relies on a stable supply voltage, but the very idea of them is to provide a stable output regardless of the supply voltage. The main thing to be careful of is to provide adequate filtering on the reference. Here's one recommended method from the [LM4040 voltage reference datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm4040-n.pdf):

[image: LM4040 voltage reference usage]

While the internal band gap reference may be accurate enough for your application another option to play it safe may be to design your PCB with footprints for the reference and leave it unpopulated if it ends up not being required. The above reference is in a SOT-23 package and you can easily find the three passives in a 0603 package.